# É possivel chamar uma função em python através de uma DLL em C?

Tags: python, c, dll

Eu tenho um programa comercial que faz um calculos e me permite calcular algo para realimentar a simulação a cada passo de tempo através de um codigo DLL em C.

Eu preciso fazer otimizações matematicas e meus codigos estão em python, teria alguma maneira de chamar minha função em python do codigo em C da dll?

Obs: Minha função recebe variaveis, calcula algumas coisas, e retorna outros valores.

Comment: por favor, traduza sua pergunta. Voce esta no stack overflow em português

Comment: @Lucas Traduzido, Obrigado.

Comment: Bem vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português! Sua pergunta parece ter alguns problemas e sua experiência aqui no Stack Overflow em Português poderá não ser a que melhor por causa disto. Queremos que você se dê bem aqui e consiga o que quer, mas para isso precisamos que você faça sua parte. Veja algumas orientações que vão te ajudar: [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/101). "Tem uma maneira?" é uma pergunta muito aberta. A resposta é sim, tem e está respondido, aó quer que alguém mostre como faz, já não tem um pergunta específica.